# EWS get Email Message Body from replied from Thunderbird

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS (Exchange 2010 SP1) and I am working with emails (subject,recipients,body).
My problem is that when I am asking these information's everything is fine except the body of the email, because I need only the newly added message (for example if I reply for a past email) but I am getting back the whole body of the email.

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(new[] { ItemSchema.UniqueBody, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.CcRecipients, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients });
            propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
            email.Load(propSet);
```

This is important for me because i need to insert each email reply to DB.

If is use the webmail client everything is fine, but when I`m using Thunderbird this issue occurs.

Any suggestions??

Comment: *Thunderbird this issue occurs.* means ? with other mail client your code is work and it give you only main body part only ? i worked with exchange so i may help you but please clear my doubt first

Comment: Hi Jageen, I have tested, and in another mail client the same probelem occurs (It gives me back the whole email body). I don`t need the past email, only the newly added email reply. There is some separator or some kind of universal separator for all email clients? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no separator (i think). Do one thing go to thunder bird and open that mail, now in "other action" you will find option "view source",Now you can see what EWS return when you ask for body. It may help you to build some logic